# USB Internet is not working in sleep mode

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb, internet, data-connection

I am using Micromax Funbook Pro. The USB Internet connection gets disconnected after the system goes into sleep mode after 1 minute. I want to keep the connection alive. Please help.

Comment: Are you talking about USB data dongle?

Answer (score 1):

I use the [WakeLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.wl) app when transferring data, to prevent my device going to sleep. It's simple but effective.